# cannot find symbol (doesn't recognize methods inside GregorianCalendar)

Tags: methods, parameters, arguments, symbols, gregorian-calendar

Issue:

```
CalendarTest.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
    int today = d.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                   ^
symbol:   method get(int)
location: variable d of type GregorianCalendar
```

My code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class CalendarTest
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    GregorianCalendar d = new GregorianCalendar();

    int today = d.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
 }
}
```

So, what I've done so far was checking the API (methods get and set won't work at all).
I've also been searching stackoverflow and google to get some help about the issue, but without any positive results.

Tried switching between Java 6 and Java 7 without any result at all.
Been doing this for Calendar instead of GregorianCalendar, but the problem still remains.

I'm operating on Ubuntu 12.04. I've no clue what's wrong since those methods are included in GregorianCalendar class (as far as API says so)

Also,

```
CalendarTest.java:8: error: constructor GregorianCalendar in class GregorianCalendar cannot be applied to given types;
GregorianCalendar asd = new GregorianCalendar(2000, 10, 25);
                        ^
required: no arguments
found: int,int,int
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

won't work as well. It says that parameters (int, int, int) are wrong. Well it shouldn't, should it?

Please help me get past this, since I can not move any further (doing Core JAVA 2 Basics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've posted is fine. I strongly suspect you've got another class called `GregorianCalendar` on your classpath. I suggest you look for it and remove it. Note that `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` itself appears to be found correctly.

One thing you might want to try (just to see which package is at fault) is explicitly specifying the types:

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar d = new java.util.GregorianCalendar();
int today = d.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

I suspect that will work, in which case you should look for a `GregorianCalendar` type in the default package.

If that's *still* not working, it suggests your Java installation is broken.

Comment: Hi Jon, 
Thanks for the answer. I'm a newbie.
I have no idea, whether or not I did anything you asked me for, but I typed in my command line the following

    `echo $CLASSPATH`

and it returned nothing at all.

I've tried explicitly specifying the types and pasted your code, so the compilation shows me
    `error: Class names, 'CalendarTest', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested`

So, any idea how to fix it, so I won't have to explicitly specify the types?

Comment: Ok, the problem was because I forgot to type in .java when compiling. Anyways, it works. Could you please tell me how to fix it, so that I won't have to specify the types explicitly? Quick how-to would be appreciated.

Comment: @Patrick: Just get rid of the `GregorianCalendar` type which you've apparently got somewhere. Look at all the Java files in the current directory - my guess is that one of them declares `GregorianCalendar`.

Comment: You were absolutely right. That was so lame of me to name the Java file the same as the class that is currently implemented inside... Thank you, I'd give you some UP, but I can not! Cheers <3

Comment: @Patrick: You may not be able to vote, but you can accept this answer if it helped you - you click on the tick near the vote count. (Only if it was actually helpful, of course.)